# How to remove bluetooth application from startup in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service

I am debugging Bluetooth chip on Android and the default `Bluetooth` application interferes with native testing tools written in C `e.g scotest,hstest`.

So what I want is to disable the `Android Java Bluetooth` service completely but not disabling the native blueZ service `i.e not being able to interact with Bluetooth from GUI but only from adb` and making sure that there are no Bluetooth activities running at all except the native tools launched by me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the entry from the list of product_packages in below file :

```
  android_source/build/target/product/generic.mk.
```

Then compile the source code, and flash the image on to your device.

Comment: I can't find a list `product_packages` in `android_source/build/target/product/generic.mk.` also I am building for pandaboard .

Comment: Do the changes in android_source_ics/build/target/product/generic_no_telephony.mk file. Remove the Bluetooth entry in PRODUCT_PACKAGES list. Then compile the source and try

Comment: This isn't working I can turn on and off bluetooth from gui .